# Improve this jQuery?

Tags: jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

was wondering if anyone could help me improve my code. Its just some basic checkbox selections, but I know that there must be some shorter ways of doing things.

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".sendType").click(function() {
                    var what_is = $(this).attr("name");
                    var p = new RegExp('.*?(\\d+).*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+))',["i"]);
                    var m = p.exec(what_is);
                    if (m != null) {
                        check_all(m[1], m[2], (this).checked);
                    } 
                });
                $(".controlType").click(function() {
                    var what_is = $(this).attr("name");
                    check_all(0, what_is, (this).checked);
                }); 
                function check_all(id, what, check) {
                    all = $("input:checkbox");
                    sa = $("input:checkbox.sendType."+id);
                    sac = $("input:checkbox:checked.sendType."+id).length;
                    sw = $("input:checkbox.sendType."+what);
                    if (id == 0) {
                        if (what == 'all') {
                            all.attr('checked', check);
                        } else {
                            sw.attr('checked', check);
                        }
                    }
                    if (what == 'all') {
                        sa.attr('checked', check);
                    } else {
                        if (sac == 2) {
                            if (check === true) {
                                sa.attr('checked', true);
                            } else {
                                $("input:checkbox.sendType.all."+id).attr('checked', false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ce = $("input:checkbox.controlType.email");
                    ct = $("input:checkbox.controlType.text");
                    s2 = $("input:checkbox:not(:checked).sendType.email").length;
                    s3 = $("input:checkbox:not(:checked).sendType.text").length;
                    if (!s2) {
                        ce.attr('checked', true);
                    } else {
                        ce.attr('checked', false);
                    }
                    if (!s3) {
                        ct.attr('checked', true);
                    } else {
                        ct.attr('checked', false);
                    }
                    if (!s3 && !s2) {
                        all.attr('checked', true);
                    } else {
                        $("input:checkbox.controlType.all").attr('checked', false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

The markup:

```
<ul class="form-section">
  <li class="form-line">
    <input type="checkbox" class="controlType all" name="all" value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="controlType email" name="email" value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="controlType text" name="text" value="1">
  </li>
  <li class="form-line">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sendType all 1" name="id[1][all]" value="Charlie Gery allen">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType email 1" name="id[1][email]" value="gery@live.com">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType text 1" name="id[1][text]" value="0412345678">
        <span id="id[1][name]">Charlie Gery allen</span>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sendType all 6" name="id[6][all]" value="ye ere ertert">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType email 6" name="id[6][email]" value="blah@sdfsd.oer">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType text 6" name="id[6][text]" value="0415698721">
        <span id="id[6][name]">ye ere ertert</span>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sendType all 7" name="id[7][all]" value="erterert utrtuuy 67678">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType email 7" name="id[7][email]" value="gggglll@mothing.com">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType text 7" name="id[7][text]" value="0598746248">
        <span id="id[7][name]">erterert utrtuuy 67678</span>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sendType all 8" name="id[8][all]" value="rrrrrrtyertertrrrrrr yyyyyyyetryeyyyyyyy">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType email 8" name="id[8][email]" value="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sendType text 8" name="id[8][text]" value="">
        <span id="id[8][name]">rrrrrrtyertertrrrrrr yyyyyyyetryeyyyyyyy</span>
  </li>
  <li class="form-line" id="id_2">
    <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="form-submit-button">Send Message</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If anyone can get to it, thanks heaps.

Cheers
Charlie

Comment: Life will be much sweeter if you use more descriptive variable names. It's hard to build a mental model of the program flow when you're staring at a sea of sa, ct, ce, s2, s3, etc. Why be a human code minifier?

Comment: It would also be nice if you told us what you want your script to do. Otherwise, first, you make people do unnecessary job, second, your script may be misinterpreted by someone, and they will give you wrong recommendations.

Comment: also see: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of optimizing both your JS code and your HTML. (to some degree)

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/dominicbarnes/ybGbU/

**HTML**

You'll notice that I've removed some classes (the "id" classes, `controlType` and `sendType` notably) and added some ids (`contact` and `control-line`) as well.

```
<ul id="contact" class="form-section">
    <li>All Email Text</li>
    <li id="control-line" class="form-line">
        <input type="checkbox" class="all" name="all" value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="email" name="email" value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="text" name="text" value="1">
    </li>
    <li class="form-line">
        <input type="checkbox" class="all" name="id[1][all]" value="Charlie Gery allen">
        <input type="checkbox" class="email" name="id[1][email]" value="gery@live.com">
        <input type="checkbox" class="text" name="id[1][text]" value="0412345678">
        <span id="id[1][name]">Charlie Gery allen</span>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line">
        <input type="checkbox" class="all" name="id[6][all]" value="ye ere ertert">
        <input type="checkbox" class="email" name="id[6][email]" value="blah@sdfsd.oer">
        <input type="checkbox" class="text" name="id[6][text]" value="0415698721">
        <span id="id[6][name]">ye ere ertert</span>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line">
        <input type="checkbox" class="all" name="id[7][all]" value="erterert utrtuuy 67678">
        <input type="checkbox" class="email" name="id[7][email]" value="gggglll@mothing.com">
        <input type="checkbox" class="text" name="id[7][text]" value="0598746248">
        <span id="id[7][name]">erterert utrtuuy 67678</span>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line">
        <input type="checkbox" class="all" name="id[8][all]" value="rrrrrrtyertertrrrrrr yyyyyyyetryeyyyyyyy">
        <input type="checkbox" class="email" name="id[8][email]" value="">
        <input type="checkbox" class="text" name="id[8][text]" value="">
        <span id="id[8][name]">rrrrrrtyertertrrrrrr yyyyyyyetryeyyyyyyy</span>
    </li>
    <li class="form-line" id="id_2">
        <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="form-submit-button">Send Message</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

I entirely rewrote this portion here, and included comments!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get and store a list of all the "non-control" checkboxes
    // ie, look in #contact for any checkbox not within #control-line
    var $checkboxes = $("#contact").find("li.form-line:not(#control-line) input:checkbox");

    // now we'll enable the "control" checkboxes
    $("#control-line input:checkbox").change(function() {
        // if the selected control box has the "all" class
        if ($(this).hasClass("all")) {
            // then set all the "non-control" checkboxes to the same state as this one
            $checkboxes.attr("checked", this.checked);
            // as well as the sibling checkboxes (email and text)
            $(this).siblings("input:checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
        } else {
            // otherwise, we only want to select a specific column, so we take the current className
            // (this will break if you add any classes here, you could use a data-* attribute instead
            $checkboxes.filter("." + this.className).attr("checked", this.checked);
        }
    });

    // now let's attach a specific event to the "all" checkboxes
    // we'll start with our cached collection from above, then filter it to find only `.all`
    $checkboxes.filter(".all").change(function() {
        // set all the checkbox siblings to the state of the current checkbox
        $(this).siblings("input:checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });
});
```